# Как создать сеттер, если атрибут имеет такое же имя, что и свойство?

Tags: python, база-данных, orm

Проблема: пересчитать хэш адреса электронной почты при его изменении. Иду в лоб:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email_hash = db.Column(db.String(32))

    @property
    def email(self):
         return self.email

    @email.setter
    def email(self, email):
        #считаем хэш
        self.email_hash=hash
        self.email = email
```

Выход это поменять имя аттрибута на _email, чтобы оно не конфликтовало с именем свойства, но такой способ не приемлем, так как класс является отображением реальных таблиц, в которых нижние подчеркивания и прочее шаманства с именами не допустимы.

Answer (score 1):

Соответствие между именем атрибута и именем поля в таблице легко изменить:

```
_email = db.Column('email', db.String(120), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Модель не является отображением реальных таблиц, модель – это сущность предметной области. Подобные отличия позволяют поселить в модели больше логики.

Правда, такой вариант неочевиден – я ни разу не встречал его "в бою" и про подобные хитрости ничего нет в документации.

Для реализации подобных манипуляций чаще используется метод `save`. Конечно, хэш не будет появляться на лету, а только после сохранения в БД, но обычно этого достаточно. Пример:

```
class User(db.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.hash = md5(self.email)
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[Другой пример в документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods).

Comment: Интересно, но как я понял здесь переопределяется родительский метод save(), в SQLAlchemy всё несколько иначе. Кроме того, ведь тогда остаётся возможность выстрелить себе в ногу путём: `vasya.email = 'anothermail@example.com #save() не будет вызван - хэш не пересчитается`

Comment: В Алхимии для этого есть [MapperEvents](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert). Нашёл [нужный стучай в документации Алхимии](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_attributes.html#using-descriptors-and-hybrids), там есть ответ на вопрос. @sergey-gornostaev предложил правильный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылочку, то что нужно. Похоже на то, что предложил @sergey-gornostaev + какие-то специальные БД-ориентированные методы.